# useState variable not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I'm having issue in understanding the behavior of React useState hook. Please have a look at my code first.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function UseEffectHook() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count++)}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(++count)}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count+1)}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1)}>Decrement</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default UseEffectHook
```

I'm wondering why the first and second buttons aren't working.
Here, is the link to codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/useeffect-1-2pzgzw?file=%2Fsrc%2FUseEffectHook.js%3A1%2C9

**Note:** It'd be appreciated if someone could explain this concept in details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count++` and `++count` try to change the value in `count`, but that's impossible because it's a `const`. As a result, the first two buttons throw the error you're seeing: "Type Error Assignment to constant variable". It doesn't get far enough call `setCount`, so this has nothing to do with the behavior of react state, it's just about the fact you're trying to change a const.

The solution is to just not do what you have done in buttons 1 and 2. Buttons 3 and 4 are the correct ways to set state.